# Extension of $\sigma$-additive measure beyond Lebesgue-measurable sets.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* an unproven statement saying that the system of sets of $\sigma$-uniqueness for a $\sigma$-additive measure $m$ defined on a semiring $\mathscr{S}_m$ -and therefore uniquely extendible to the minimal ring $\mathscr{R}(\mathscr{S}_m)$- coincides with the sets of Lebesgue-measurable sets with respect to $m$. The statement, which is a proofless statement in the original text, appears in the form of problem 15 in an English translation [here](http://librarum.org/book/10022/146).

The fact that every Lebesgue-measurable set is a set of $\sigma$-uniqueness is virtually proven in the "hint", but what I find uncomprehensible is why the extension [$\mu$](http://librarum.org/book/10022/146) of $m$, which is defined on $\mathscr{R}(\mathscr{S}_m)$ and on $A$, is also defined on $A\triangle B$ with $B\in\mathscr{R}(\mathscr{S}_m)$ (we can find $\mu(A\triangle B)$ in the [text](http://librarum.org/book/10022/146)): is that implicit in the definition of $\sigma$-*additive extension of $m$ defined on* $A$?

As to the converse, i.e. the fact that a $\sigma$-additive extension of $m$ to a larger system than the system of Lebesgue-measurable sets is not unique, I am not able to verify why it is true. Can anybody prove it or help me in any way?

I heartily thank you for any answer!!!